# dealing with a malformed soap fault

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I'm writing a SOAP client against a server that's producing a Fault that is not up-to-spec.  Specifically, the `lang` attribute is missing in the `Text` element in the Fault Reason ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#reasontextelement)).  I'm using Spring WS 2.4.0.  Is there a way to intercept the response and inject the attribute before it gets parsed into a `SaajSoapMessage`?  I tried creating a ClientInterceptor, but the xml has already been parsed by the time it hits the interceptor.  Would I need to create my own MessageFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313568) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053113).

When I instantiated my `WebServiceGatewaySupport`, I added a `ClientInterceptor` where I configured the `handleFault()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    LOGGER.debug("intercepted a fault.");
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    WebServiceMessage response = messageContext.getResponse();
    Source source = response.getPayloadSource();
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());

    try {
        Transformer displayTransformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        displayTransformer.transform(source, streamResult);
        LOGGER.debug("\t>> initial response\n" + streamResult.getWriter().toString());

        StreamSource xslSource = new StreamSource(new File(
                FaultInterceptor.class.getResource("/SoapFaultFix.xsl").getFile()
        ));
        Transformer modifyingTransformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);
        modifyingTransformer.transform(source, response.getPayloadResult());

    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

This simply takes the source xml and runs it through an xsl transformation.  It's important to begin with an [identity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) so you don't lose content.  I then added the attribute and value, then dropped in the existing value.  My `SoapFaultFix.xsl` looked like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
>
    <xsl:template match="/ | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//soapenv:Fault/soapenv:Reason/soapenv:Text">
        <soapenv:Text>
            <xsl:attribute name="xml:lang">en</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </soapenv:Text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I liked this approach because I found drilling into the DOM was arduous with pure Java, and I could easily expand the xsl to make other changes.